# mongodb projection matching sub array

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new to mongodb.I have a mongodb document whose structure is like this :

```
"prices": {
     "0": {
       "Quantity": {
         "1": "10",
         "2": "14",
         "5": "16",
      },
       "option1": "a4",
       "option2": "50",
       "option3": "qwe",
       "option4": "sdslk" 
    },
     "1": {
       "Quantity": {
         "1": "20",
         "2": "12",
         "10": "3",
      },
       "option1": "a5",
       "option2": "100",
       "option3": "kl",
       "option4": "oiuio" 
    },
     "2": {
       "Quantity": {
         "10": "20",
         "15": "12",
         "100": "3",
      },
       "option1": "a2",
       "option2": "10",
       "option3": "kadl",
       "option4": "qwqw" 
    },
    ...
}
```

I have an array in PHP like this

```
Array => ("option1" => "a2",
           "option2"=> "10",
           "option3"=> "kadl",
           "option4"=> "qwqw" 
)
```

I want to query the document such that it matches a particular sub array in the mongodb doc and return the following result

```
"2": {
   "Quantity": {
   "10": "20",
   "15": "12",
   "100": "3",
},
"option1": "a2",
"option2": "10",
"option3": "kadl",
"option4": "qwqw" 
}
```

But only when all the correspoding values (except Quantity match).
The options (option1, option2, ...) are different for different documents.
Please comment is question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Not possible since you don't know the name of the key to match to. Perhaps you want `prices` to actually be an array?

```
 { "prices" : [{ 
    "Quantity": {
        "10": "20",
        "15": "12",
        "100": "3",
     },
     "option1": "a2",
     "option2": "10",
     "option3": "kadl",
     "option4": "qwqw" 
}] }
```

Then you can get what you want like this:

```
db.test.find({ "prices" : { "$elemMatch" : { "option1" : "a2", "option2" : "10", "option3" : "kadl", "option4" : "qwqw" } } }, { "prices.$" : 1 })
```